# How can I enable promisucous mode on vmware workstation for windows host?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I googled and only found instructions for Linux for 5.5. http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_advanced_linux_vadapter_promiscuous.html

I am using Vmware Workstation 8.0.

I thought it would be under the Edit -> Virtual Network Editor but didn't find it.

Thanks